# Running SQL queries in Tarantool from Go are silent (no errors)

Tags: go, tarantool

I try to run SQL queries from a Golang application using the official Tarantool client. The only way I know how to do it is by using `conn.Eval` like below. But I don't receive any errors. I can drop non existing tables, insert rows with duplicate keys. I will never find out that something went wrong.

```golang
resp, err := conn.Eval("box.execute([[TRUNCATE TABLE not_exists;]])", []interface{}{})
// err is always nil
// resp.Error is always empty
```

Can you point out the way to get errors or the right way to run SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the question!

I have talked to the team and we have two options for you. Here is the first one:

```
  resp, err := conn.Eval("return box.execute([[TRUNCATE TABLE \"not_exists\";]])", []interface{}{})
      
  if len(resp.Tuples()) > 1 {
  fmt.Println("Error", resp.Tuples()[1])  
  }else{
  fmt.Println("Result", resp.Tuples()[0])  
  }
```

And here is the second one:

```
 r, err := tnt.Eval("local data, err = box.execute(...) return data or box.error(err)", []interface{}{
  `TRUNCATE table "not_exists";`,
 })
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatalln(err)
 }
```

I hope that helps! And if it doesn't - let me know and we will look into this one more time.